# Flutter run ERROR saying Offset method not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart

> flutter run

```
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3132:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(42.1791543883521, 10.076022296832232),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3134:12: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
          <Offset>[
           ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3135:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(18.0395385, 35.0694285),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3136:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(17.930325848774086, 35.009922992806736),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3137:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(17.547570026086344, 34.79006469124885),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3138:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(16.77400634956471, 34.28806903036052),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3139:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(15.420844231339236, 33.190072627931144),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3140:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(13.244382836612694, 30.510686536014962),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3141:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(11.409353826406043, 23.05882750860248),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3142:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(15.029393510076535, 14.865698083357398),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3143:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(19.119657851027682, 11.732035307116437),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3144:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(22.181561433566472, 10.327194014492921),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3145:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(24.549319100345187, 9.637024560095686),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3146:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(26.406516506834194, 9.36448501672809),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3147:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(27.85067669401468, 9.342322127398774),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3148:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(28.962368129917518, 9.43950727109096),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3149:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(29.807762692890815, 9.582022806077507),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3150:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(30.438561431422848, 9.729770800155638),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3151:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(30.89419677764727, 9.861451665612325),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3152:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(31.20484153286095, 9.966826116941988),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3153:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(31.39360858309835, 10.041768004618815),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3154:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(31.479212581732742, 10.084288975986702),
            ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3156:12: Error: 'Offset' isn't a type.
          <Offset>[
           ^^^^^^
../../../../Documents/FlutterSoftware/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart:3157:13: Error: Method not found: 'Offset'.
            Offset(18.0395385, 35.0694285),
```

I already update my flutter package . I'm working on Ubuntu 20 , VSCodium , pixel emulator and java 8  .
Just now i setup the flutter things and it takes around 3 days by clearing all errors , and i didn't edit any flutter , android or gredle files but still i'm getting this error .

> flutter analyze --flutter-repo

> flutter update-packages

I run this command suggested at fultter github wiki page , But no use
please help me to figure it out.

Thank you